# how to update realm object based on the certain property in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have products in my Realm database like this
[image]

I want to update my realm database based on productID, so I don't need to add another product over and over again. let say ***I want to update quantity of product that has productID = "a" to be 5***.

I have tried to write something like this.

```
        let selectedProductID = "a"
        let productsInRealmDatabase = realm.objects(Product.self)
        let productIndex = productsInRealmDatabase.index(where: {$0.productID == selectedProductID})
        
        if let productIndex = productIndex {
        
        do {
            
            try realm.write {
                var productRealm = productsInRealmDatabase[productIndex]
                productRealm.quantity = 5
                productsInRealmDatabase[productIndex] = productRealm // ERROR HERE
            }
            
        } catch {
            // error Handling
        }
        
        
    }
```

but I got error in : `productsInRealmDatabase[productIndex] = productRealm`

> Error Message: Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only

so how to update realm object based on the certain property in Realm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Realm`'s own `filter` method which accepts an `NSPredicate` and returns an auto-updating `Results` instance rather than Swift's `filter` when operating on `Realm` collections. Than either update the properties of the fetched prouduct or create a new one and save that to `Realm`.

```
let selectedProductID = "a"
let productsInRealmDatabase = realm.objects(Product.self)
let matchingProduct = productsInRealmDatabase.filter("productID == %@", selectedProductID).first

if let matchingProduct = matchingProduct {
    do {
        try realm.write {
            matchingProduct.quantity = 5
        }
    } catch {
        // error Handling
    }
} else {
    let newProduct = Product()
    newProduct.productID = selectedProductID
    newProduct.quantity = 5
    do {
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(newProduct)
        }
    } catch {
        // error Handling
    }
}
```

If you want your `Product`s to be unique based on their `productID` property, you use also set `productID` as the `primaryKey` of your `Object` subclass.

```
class Product:Object {
    @objc dynamic var productID = ""
    ...
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "productID"
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: It would slightly help with future app support if instead of `"productID == %@"`it was `"\(#keyPath(Product.productID)) = %@"`.

Comment: sir, could you please help me again with this one? maybe you know the answer. thanks in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790612/how-to-avoid-adding-the-same-data-in-realm-database-in-many-to-many-relationship?noredirect=1#comment94435702_53790612

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
let selectedProductID = "a"
let productsInRealmDatabase = realm.objects(Product.self)
let filteredProducts = productsInRealmDatabase.filter("productID = \(selectedProductID)")

do {
    try realm.write {
        filteredProducts.forEach { product in
            product.quantity = 5
        }
    }
} catch {
    // error Handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While inserting data to your database inside the insert function mark update key as true and then try updating the value. eg:

```
   static func insertData() {

        //Your insertion code//
         try! realm.write {
                realm.add(request, update:  true)
            }
   }


   static func updateData(productId: String, quantity: Int) {

    let product = self.getProductData(prodId: productId)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        product?.quantity = quantity
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you out.